# Did DAO attacker gained ETH on Ethereum Classic?

Tags: the-dao, dao, attacks

I'm starting to study blockchain's world and the DAO attack caught my attention.

I studied how it worked and the solution proposed by the Ethereum community.

The hard fork splitted the blockchain in 2:

- Ethereum
- Ethereum classic

in the Ethereum the blockchain has been reverted into the state before the malicious transactions made by the attacker that drained the DAO balance.
But this change didn't took place in the ethereum classic blockchain.

Does this mean that in the Ethereum classic blockchain the attacker successfully stole ETC from DAO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right. The hacker got the ETC, but not ETH. [This is his address](https://gastracker.io/addr/0x5e8f0e63e7614c47079a41ad4c37be7def06df5a)

Comment: Basically now he has €17M worth of ETC in his balance, do you know how many ETC was he able to stole?

Comment: 3642408.5276 @Carioni

Comment: So he didn't take the ethereum he stole, is he just storing it?

Comment: @Carioni In many jurisdictions, a crime is automatically forgiven after a certain number of years. I guess they are just waiting.